# Change the Screen Orientation in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

In my Application, I want to show the screens according to the Orientation. I knew, Whenever the device is Oriented then **sublayout()** method of current screen is called. According that point of view I write like this:

Here **StartUp** is another className;

This is my **LoadingScreen.java** Class;

```
public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen
{
public LoadingScreen()
{       
    createGUI();
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) 
{
    StartUp.screenOrientation();        
    if(StartUp.isLandscape)
    {
        deleteAll();
        createGUI();            
        invalidate();           
    }
    else
    {   
        deleteAll();
        orientGUI();            
        invalidate();
    }
    super.sublayout(width,height);  
}

public void createGUI()
{
    //For LANDSCAPE Display;
}

public void orientGUI()
{
    //For PORTRAIT Display;
}   
}
```

The **screenOrientation()** method is this:

```
public static void screenOrientation()
{
    if(Display.getOrientation()==Display.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)     
    {
        isLandscape=true;
        width=480;
        height=360;
    }
    else
    {
        isLandscape=false;
        width=360;
        height=480;
    }
}
```

I am getting the Screen in both Orientation Modes. My problem is, if I take one textboxField and enter something in LANDSCAPE Mode and Oriented to PORTRAIT Mode then the data is gone. Because I am calling createGUI(); or orientGUI(); methods in **sublayout()**.

One more problem that I am getting  in Touch screen is:

> If I want to enter text in any textboxField It opens the "keypad". Its Not a problem. The main thing is whenever the keypad open/hide both times again calling the **sublayout()** of that class. So I am getting the refreshed screen.

So, is there any other method to get Orientation? If it is then help me.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the first issue, you have two options.

- Dont delete the fields, just redraw the screen for the different
  orientation.

or

- Save the value of `textboxfield` before you delete the field and
  after orientation change, set the value of `textboxfield` with the
  saved value. You will need to even get the cursor position and set
  that as well.

To solve the second issue

After orientation change, set a new variable "`currentWidth`" as `Display.getWidth()` . Then when you get a call to `sublayout()` check the `Display.getWidth()` and see if its equal to `currentWidth`. If its equal that means the orientation hasn't changed. If not then the orientation has changed.

hope this helps

Comment: I don't know how to redraw the screen?

Comment: by redraw i mean "dont delete the fields", just reset the sizes of the buttons, change the background image if you have etc.etc.