# How to set Orientation of Screen in Landscape and Portrait mode in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How to Set Position of Components in Portrait Mode.and
when i Change it to Landscape Mode than Position of Components are 
Shown in Different Way.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789734/auto-rotation-on-blackberry-programming/7789839#7789839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for change Orientation of screen
This is my LoadingScreen.
Here StartUp is another className.where we make ScreenOrientation Method.

```
    public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen
{
public LoadingScreen()
{       
    createGUI();
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) 
{
    StartUp.screenOrientation();        
    if(StartUp.isLandscape)
    {
        deleteAll();
        createGUI();            
        invalidate();           
    }
    else
    {   
        deleteAll();
        orientGUI();            
        invalidate();
    }
    super.sublayout(width,height);  
}

public void createGUI()
{
    //For LANDSCAPE Display;
}

public void orientGUI()
{
    //For PORTRAIT Display;
}   
}
```

The ScreenOrientation Method:

```
 public static void screenOrientation()
{
    if(Display.getOrientation()==Display.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)     
    {
        isLandscape=true;
        width=480;
        height=360;
    }
    else
    {
        isLandscape=false;
        width=360;
        height=480;
    }
}
```

Comment: Above solution is getting from this question..... Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518394/change-the-screen-orientation-in-blackberry

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Specifying_display_direction_of_screen_647783_11.jsp

Comment: Actually i want to change positions of components in Portrait and Landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

You can use **subLayout()** Method of MainSceen for this.
try this

```
     protected void sublayout(final int width, final int height) {

 switch (Display.getOrientation()) {
 case Display.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
      {
        do something
      }
     break;
 case Display.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
      {
        do something
      }
     break;

 }

  super.sublayout(width, height);
 }
```