# forcing device orientation blackberry webworks bb10

Tags: html, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

i look for my html5 app is always in landscape, i read this [Change the Screen Orientation in Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518394/change-the-screen-orientation-in-blackberry) and [Blackberry Force Screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962512/blackberry-force-screen-orientation) but the solutions are presented for java development on platforms oldest, the current blackberry 10. I want to js +html5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done in the **config.xml** file. Just add this...

`<feature id="blackberry.app">
    <param name="orientation" value="landscape" />
</feature>`

For more information you can visit the BlackBerry developer site which has a lot of docs, samples, and getting started guides.

http://developer.blackberry.com/